# How to order rows in Mysql with a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to do order in Mysql, when need to `ORDER BY FIELD_id DESC,` but first row must be row with a `FIELD_id = 5`

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional ordering:

```
ORDER BY Field_id = 5 DESC, field_id DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4080c/2)

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could sort by such a boolean-like condition. But even without that, you could sort by something like `if(Field_id = 5, 0, 1)` or the more cross database compatible `case when Field_id = 5 then 0 else 1 end, field_id DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

you should either do it from application, or you can do union

```
SELECT field_id, ... FROM table WHERE field_id = 5

UNION

SELECT field_id, ... FROM table WHERE field_id != 5 ORDER BY field_id
```

Comment: I would use `union all`. `union` is slower and has the possibly undesirable side effect of removing duplicate rows. Apart from that, this particular problem can be solved in a much easier way without union, even if you disregard the fact that MySQL can sort by a boolean condition like sgeddes @suggested. Also, doesn't `order by` apply to the whole result, if so (and I think it does) this answer won't work.